# Illegal attempt to map a non collection as a @OneToMany, @ManyToMany or @CollectionOfElements: (Already tried other posts suggestions)

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, many-to-many, one-to-many

I wanted to make this:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IwCrT.png)
A many to many relation whit an entity in the niddle
so i created 2 entities, both One-to-may and the new entity with 2 many-to-many relations

Also i read that the collection mapping using the one-to-many annotation must be  one of these (java.util.Set, java.util.Collection, java.util.List, java.util.Map, java.util.SortedSet, java.util.SortedMap)

What am i missing ??

```
package com.SplitTable.model;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;

import javax.persistence.CascadeType;
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.OneToMany;
import javax.persistence.Table;
import javax.persistence.Temporal;
import javax.persistence.TemporalType;

@Entity
@Table(name="Fechas") 
public class Fecha implements Serializable {
    
    @Id
    @Column(name = "fecha_ID")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id=null;
    
    @Column(name="fecha", unique = true)
    @Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
    private Date fecha;
    
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "Fecha", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private Set<Registro> Registros_fecha = new HashSet<>();
    
    public Fecha(Date fecha) {
        this.fecha=fecha;
    }

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public Date getFecha() {
        return fecha;
    }

    public void setFecha(Date fecha) {
        this.fecha = fecha;
    }

    public Set<Registro> getRegistros() {
        return Registros_fecha;
    }

    public void setRegistros(Set<Registro> registros) {
        Registros_fecha = registros;
    }
    
    
    
}
```

```
@Entity
@Table(name="Registros")
public class Registro {
    @Id
    @Column(name = "registro_Id")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;
    
    @ManyToMany
    @JoinColumn(name="fecha_id")
    @Column(name="fecha")
    private Fecha fecha;

    @ManyToMany
    @JoinColumn(name="column_id")
    @Column(name="columna")
    private Columna columna;
    
    @Column(name="valor") // valor de la columna
    private Integer val;
    
    public Registro(Fecha fec, Columna col ,Integer val) {
        this.fecha=fec;
        this.columna=col;
        this.val=val;
    }
    

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public Fecha getFecha() {
        return fecha;
    }

    public void setFecha(Fecha fecha) {
        this.fecha = fecha;
    }

    public Columna getCol() {
        return columna;
    }

    public void setCol(Columna col) {
        this.columna = col;
    }

    public Integer getVal() {
        return val;
    }

    public void setVal(Integer val) {
        this.val = val;
    }
```

```
package com.SplitTable.model;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;

import javax.persistence.CascadeType;
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.OneToMany;
import javax.persistence.Table;

@Entity
@Table(name="Columnas")
public class Columna implements Serializable{
    
    @Id
    @Column(name = "columna_ID")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id=null;
    

    @Column(name="columna", unique = true)
    private String columna;
    
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "Columna", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private Set<Registro> Registros_columna = new HashSet<>();
    
    public Columna(String columna) {
        this.columna=columna;
    }
        public Long getId() {
            return id;
        }
        
        public void setId(Long id) {
            this.id = id;
        }
        
        public String getColumna() {
            return columna;
        }
        
        public void setColumna(String columna) {
            this.columna = columna;
        }
        
        public Set<Registro> getRegistros() {
            return Registros_columna;
        }
        
        public void setRegistros(Set<Registro> registros) {
            Registros_columna = registros;
        }
    }
```

I wanted to make something like this
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R2JXv.png)

The error says that i am not using the annotations correctly but i think i am

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at com.SplitTable.test.Schema_Creation_test.main(Schema_Creation_test.java:14)
Caused by: org.hibernate.AnnotationException: Illegal attempt to map a non collection as a @OneToMany, @ManyToMany or @CollectionOfElements: com.SplitTable.model.Registro.columna
    at org.hibernate.cfg.annotations.CollectionBinder.getCollectionBinder(CollectionBinder.java:325)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationBinder.processElementAnnotations(AnnotationBinder.java:1977)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationBinder.processIdPropertiesIfNotAlready(AnnotationBinder.java:968)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationBinder.bindClass(AnnotationBinder.java:793)
    at org.hibernate.boot.model.source.internal.annotations.AnnotationMetadataSourceProcessorImpl.processEntityHierarchies(AnnotationMetadataSourceProcessorImpl.java:225)
    at org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess$1.processEntityHierarchies(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:239)
    at org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess.complete(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:282)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.metadata(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:1460)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:1494)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider.createEntityManagerFactory(HibernatePersistenceProvider.java:56)
    at javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:79)
    at javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:54)
    at com.SSimport.utils.JPA_Utils.<clinit>(JPA_Utils.java:8)
    ... 1 more
```

Comment: Revisit your Registro 'fetcha' and 'columna' relationships, as it isn't clear why a Registro would have only a single fetcha and columna instance and that you'd try to map them as a ManyToMany. Look at your image again, as you are missing or incorrectly mapping your 'orderDetail' intermediary entity with ManyToMany mappings when your diagram shows it should be using ManyToOne